# npm warning for not installed/outdated package

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

When i ran `npm install` i get the following warnings:

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
```

I do not have `har-validator` in my `package.json`, and `uuid` is in my package set to version 9.

Why do i get this error, and how to fix these?

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "dateformat": "^4.6.3",
    "dns-packet": "^5.4.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "joi": "^17.6.4",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^4.11.0",
    "mqtt-packet": "^8.1.2",
    "semver": "^7.5.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "ws": "^8.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.24.0",
    "grunt": "^1.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-compress": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^5.0.1",
    "grunt-env": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-run": "^0.8.1",
    "minimist": "^1.2.6",
    "mocha": "^9.2.2",
    "mocha.parallel": "^0.15.6",
    "newman": "^6.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "sinon": "^14.0.2"
  }
```

Comment: Do you have _transitive_ dependencies on those packages? Try `npm explain [spec]`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@jonrsharpe's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77769209/npm-warning-for-not-installed-outdated-package?noredirect=1#comment137104775_77769209), I found out this is caused by `newman`:

```bash
$ npm explain har-validator
har-validator@5.1.5 dev
node_modules/har-validator
  har-validator@"~5.1.3" from postman-request@2.88.1-postman.33
  node_modules/postman-request
    postman-request@"2.88.1-postman.33" from newman@6.0.0
    node_modules/newman
      dev newman@"^6.0.0" from the root project
    postman-request@"2.88.1-postman.33" from postman-runtime@7.33.0
    node_modules/postman-runtime
      postman-runtime@"7.33.0" from newman@6.0.0
      node_modules/newman
        dev newman@"^6.0.0" from the root project
```

Installing newman into a empty project/folder gives the exact same error:

```bash
$ npm init --yes
Wrote to /tmp/test-newman/package.json:

{
  "name": "test-newman",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}


$ npm install newman
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

added 117 packages, and audited 118 packages in 2s

9 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```